# s.assign is not a function when setting bsActivePane with a number

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-strap

I'm trying to set the active pane of a pair of tabs programmatically as part of interface. When I set it with a number, which appears to be the correct way looking at the docs, I get the following error.

```
Error: s.assign is not a function
.link/<@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.6/angular-strap.min.js:9:13383
```

There's only one `.assign` call in the uncompressed version of that file, which is on [line 3280](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/v2.1.6/dist/angular-strap.js#L3280). Looking at that line, unless `$parse` is doing some seriously clever stuff, it would appear that I'm trying to call `.assign` on a number, which I assume is the wrong thing.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a quick way to fix it (assuming it's a semi-complex problem)?

Sample HTML

```
<div class="full-height" data-fade="1" data-bs-tabs="" data-bs-active-pane="{{ controller.getActiveTab() }}">
    <div data-title="Tab 1" data-bs-pane="">
        <!-- Injected content of tab 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="full-height" data-title="Tab 2" data-bs-pane="">
        <!-- Injected content of tab 2 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welp, [reproduced](http://plnkr.co/edit/5JJBGL7Rml451zIOGRv3?p=preview). It seems to work, despite the error. I hope you get some answers to this. I've had so much grief with this library that I have stopped using it in favor of [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs). Man, if its not too late to jump ship now...

Comment: To all that come here: @salniro is right, use UI Bootstrap if you can

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use a function or a fixed value with the attribute helper as the directive will try to update the value whenever the user change tab.
If you replace your function with a variable, your code will work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="full-height" data-fade="1" data-bs-tabs="" data-bs-active-pane="activePanel">
    <div data-title="Tab 1" data-bs-pane="">
        <!-- Injected content of tab 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="full-height" data-title="Tab 2" data-bs-pane="">
        <!-- Injected content of tab 2 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.activePanel = 1; // This is the initial active panel.
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/v0cWe8smkC3LGKvJ3qn1?p=preview)